# Как сохраняя activeRecord в Yii1 обновлять только измененные поля?

Tags: php, yii

В проекте начали присходить ошибки перезаписи данных. Например пока выполняется долгая транзакция в которой мы, кроме всего другого, обновляем клиенту статус на 'status2', в месте в другом методе, который был запущен позже транзакции есть код:

```
$client = Client::model()->findByPk($clientId);
$client->name = 'Вася';
$client->save(false);
```

В итоге статус перезаписывается обратно на 'status1'. Потому-что activeRecord обновляет все поля.

Что бы обновить только name, мы должны прописать:

```
$client->save(false, ['name']);
```

Во многих местах проекта есть похожий код:

```
$client->doSomething();
//В методе doSomething, например код:
//$this->status = 'someStatus';
//$this->someField = 'value';
$client->save(false);
```

При сохранении клиента мы не можем написать перечень полей, т.к. в самом методе doSomething не происходит сохранения, а оно происходит снаружи и нам придется при каждом изменении метода, менять массив полей для сохранения везде где он применяется.

Есть ли способ обновлять только те поля, которые были изменены? В yii2 есть метод getDirtyAttributes который возвращает изменные поля, но как это сделать в Yii1?

Comment: На англоязычном SO есть решение - сделать этот функционал в своём [ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461503/yii-on-update-detect-if-a-specific-ar-property-has-been-changed-on-beforesave)

Comment: Пора переезжать тебе на yii2, хотя не торопись, ходят слуги что yii3 на подходе..